# HTML button submits the last row instead of selected row from PHP SQL query

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a sql query which gets the data from a db table. and it gets all four rows from the table which is fine. 
And i also have a html button to insert the selected row data to another table in db with php insert.

But the problem is, after getting all the five rows information, when i click on the submit button for third row or any row, it inserts the data from the last row alone.

Seems like there is some alignment problem with my sql.

My html/sql code as goes:

```
<?php 
    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM landlordsignups ";
    $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
    if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {                               
    while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {                                   
?>
<form action="phppage.php" method="post" id="accept">
   <tr >
       <td><?php echo ($row2["name"]); ?></a></td>
       <td><?php echo ($row2["email"]); ?></a></td>
       <td><?php echo ($row2["location"]); ?></td>
       <td><?php echo ($row2["mobile"]); ?></td>
       <td><?php echo ($row2["date2"]); ?></td>
       <td><?php echo md5($row2["password"]); ?></td>
<input type="hidden" name="name" form="accept" value="<?php echo ($row2['name']); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="email" form="accept" value="<?php echo ($row2['email']); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="location" form="accept" value="<?php echo ($row2['location']); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="mobile" form="accept" value="<?php echo ($row2['mobile']); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="password" form="accept" value="<?php echo ($row2['password']); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="id" form="reject" value="<?php echo ($row2['id']); ?>" />
      <td><button type="submit" form="accept">Accept</button></td>
</form>
<form action="someotherphppage.php" method="post" id="reject">
      <td><button type="submit" form="reject">Reject</button></td>
</form>
</tr> 
<?php     }
     } else {
    echo "0 results";
}
?>
```

My PHP code for Accept button as goes:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = md5($_POST['password']);
$location = $_POST['location'];
$mobile = $_POST['mobile'];

$date = date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$date = date('M-d,Y H:i:s');
$date2 = date('M-d,Y');


$conn = new mysqli ($servername, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO table2 (name, email, password, location, mobile, date2)
VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$password', '$location', '$mobile', '$date2')";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {

echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("details have been inserted")';
echo '</script>';
echo '<a href="page.php"></a>';
}
else {
    echo "ERROR" . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

So, here, instead of inserting the selected row data, it inserts the data of the last row.

Any help is appreciated..

Comment: First - you have SQLInjection in your code, second - you will submit anything that is inside `$row2`, I don't see any `SELECT` in your code nor any checkbox or any other way to *select* row. So maybe your codes does what you tell him to do and not what you want him to do?

Comment: I agree that is not very safe this method, but I think he expects that only one form is fired, so only data inside <form> tag should be submitted. @harishk did you try to debug it with a browser tools to see  submitted POST vers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are generating forms in a loop with same ID try make your form ID unique e.g

```
<form action="phppage.php" method="post" id="accept<?php echo ($row2['id']); ?>"></form>
```

and same for reject form

Answer (score 0):

Remove all `form="..."` attributes from input, form and buttons.

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" form="reject" value="">
<button type="submit" form="accept">Accept</button>
```

to

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="">
<button type="submit">Accept</button>
```